# Django web app with Microsoft azure custom vision

Tags: python, django, azure, django-rest-framework, microsoft-custom-vision

Django web app with Microsoft azure custom vision

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to integrate Microsoft azure services like Custom vision in the Django app?

Yes, of course.

If you familiar with [python sdk about Custom vision](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-cognitiveservices-vision-customvision/?view=azure-python), you can import it's dependency. And use it in your webapp.

If not familiar with  python sdk, [you also can use restapi](https://southcentralus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/Custom_Vision_Training_3.3/operations/5eb0bcc6548b571998fddebd).